# How to change internal functions into their own functions?

Tags: java, android, oop, onclick, onclicklistener

I don't know what these are called but I want to change something like this:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

into something where the code is not "nested" inside the argument like that. In other words what I have in mind is:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(something goes here);

//...and then within its own method somewhere,

public void onClickMethodForOnClickListenerOrSomething(View view) {
    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("Action", null).show();
}
```

I have no idea if I am making myself clear but I basically want to rip out the listener as an argument and make it into a separate function. I find that it makes things cleaner because with so many listeners, there's a lot of code that accumulates in my OnCreate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your need to override the onClick method, you cannot rename it, but you can do the folliwing:

```
public void onClickMethodForOnClickListenerOrSomething(View view) {
    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    .setAction("Action", null).show();
}

public void yourOtherMethod() {
  fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          onClickMethodForOnClickListenerOrSomething(view);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `fab.setOnClickListener()` is expecting an Object of `View.OnClickListener`.

So one option is to create a new class which extends from `View.OnClickListener` and overrides the `onClick()` method. Then you can do something like

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
```

The other option is to use lambdas so something like

```
 fab.setOnClickListener((View view)->(Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can just write

```
fab.setOnClickListener(ClassName::onClickMethodForOnClickListenerOrSomething);
```

If you are not you can just call your `onClickMethodForOnClickListenerOrSomething` in the View.OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

You have an interface, OnClickListener. This interface is supposed to be implemented by a View (or its derivations). The first example in your question is **inline implementation** of an interface. I assume you would like to change/move it to a view implementing it in its own class. Something like this:

```
public class Fab implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
       .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }

}
```

usage:

```
Fab fab = new Fab()
fab.setOnClickListener(aView);
```